# Clear innerHTML after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I have the below code It works fine but I want to clear the innerHTML after 5 seconds. Not every 5 sec but when it appears, it is cleared again after 5 seconds. Once!

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = document.forms["forma"]["emri"].value;
  var x1 = document.forms["forma"]["mbiemri"].value;
  var x2 = document.forms["forma"]["email"].value;
  var x3 = document.forms["forma"]["vendbanimi"].value;
  if ((x == null || x == "") || (x1 == null || x1 == "") || (x2 == null || x2 == "") || (x3 == null || x3 == "")) {
    document.getElementById("js").innerHTML = "Ju lutem ploresojini te gjitha te dhenat";
    return false;
  }
  if (x2.indexOf("@") < 1) {
    document.getElementById("js").innerHTML = "Ju lutem insertoni nje email te sakte";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="forma">
  <center>
    <form class="form-orizontal" method="post" name="forma">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">e</span>
        <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="emri" name="emri">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">mb</span>
        <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="mbiemri" name="mbiemri">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">@</span>
        <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="email" name="email">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">vb</span>
        <input class="span2" id="prependedInput" type="text" placeholder="vendbanimi" name="vendbanimi">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">V</span>
        <select name="viti_lindjes" class="small">
          <option style="display:none">Viti i lindjes</option>
          <option>1990</option>
          <option>1991</option>
          <option>1992</option>
          <option>1993</option>
          <option>1994</option>
          <option>1995</option>
          <option>1996</option>
          <option>1997</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" onclick="return myfunction()">Submit</button>
          <input type="reset" class="btn">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="js"></div>
    </form>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show us the code that calls `myfunction()`.

Comment: it's ok now?above you have html code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[setTimeOut function waits for you](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```js
function appearing(){
  document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
  setTimeout(function(){ 
      document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML = "";
  }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<a href='#' onClick='appearing()'>Appear and disapper after 5 seconds</a>
<div id='inner'></div>
```

Comment: Yes,i want to disappear the exist appear innerHTML,not to appear after some seconds

Comment: @roliroli what am I doing the my answer?

Comment: Look my code carefuly..That code you posted it appear my innerHTML content after 5 seconds..Well,i have a submit button,when i press it appear the innerHTML content...I want when it appear ,after 5 sec to dissapear.did you understand

Comment: @roliroli I changed my code please try again with the above code.

Comment: `return appearing()` and `return false` in the function is better coding

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `setTimeout()` function.

This code should work in your situation:

```
function myfunction() {
    var x = document.forms["forma"]["emri"].value;
    var x1 = document.forms["forma"]["mbiemri"].value;
    var x2 = document.forms["forma"]["email"].value;
    var x3 = document.forms["forma"]["vendbanimi"].value;   
    if ((x == null || x == "") || (x1 == null || x1 == "") || (x2 == null || x2 == "") || (x3 == null || x3 == "") ) {
    document.getElementById("js").innerHTML = "Ju lutem ploresojini te gjitha te dhenat";
    return false;
    }
    if (x2.indexOf("@") < 1) {
        document.getElementById("js").innerHTML = "Ju lutem insertoni nje email te sakte";
    return false;
    }   
    setTimeout(functionToDisappearInnerHTML(), 5000); //Sets a timer that starts the function in 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds)
}

function functionToDisappearInnerHTML() {
    document.getElementById("js").innerHTML = ""; //Clears the innerHTML
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Put the first line of code with the setTimeout function anywhere that you make text appear.

Comment: The text appear when i press submit button.How to disappear it after 5 sec?

Comment: hahah no it doesn't!Look one more time my code!
when i press submit button then appear the innerHTML content.
well,we supose now i have press the submit button.Now i want to disappear after 5 seconds.Did you understand?

Comment: Okay, so you want it to disappear after five seconds after you press the button again?

Answer (score 0):

Guy, I got it. The text disappears after five seconds if you remove the brackets.
change this:

```
setTimeout(functionToDisappearInnerHTML(), 5000);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(functionToDisappearInnerHTML, 5000);
```